# How to ensure serial transmission and reception of required data without any garbage values in the 8051?

Tags: serial, c, uart, 8051, baudrate

I'm trying to continuously transmit the character 'L' from the microcontroller 8051 to the PC at a baud rate of 9600. The frequency of the 8051 is 16 MHz, and I accordingly loaded the BRL register with "0XFC" for baud rate generation. However, I can see a stream of garbage values on the hyper terminal; I even tried changing the auto reload values from 0xFB to 0xFF to no avail. Is there any way for me to generate the exact Baud Rate in the microcontroller or a way for me to fix this problem?

Edit: Also, even if I transmit just a single alphabet from the PC to the controller, and the code is written in a way for the controller to echo everything sent from the PC sometimes the character the controller sends in response is different from what I'd sent.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "reg_c51.h"

char uart_data='L';

void main (void) 
{
    SCON = 0x40;                     
    BDRCON &=0xE0;              
    BDRCON |=0x08;               
    BRL=0xFC;                    
    IEN0 = 0xF0;                            
    BDRCON |=0x10;              

    while(1)                  
    {
        SBUF = uart_data;
        while(TI==0);
        TI=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which 8051 (manufacturer, part number) are you using, exactly?

Comment: I'm using the AT89C5131A-L.

Comment: Might not be the issue here, but never underestimate the ability of plain old wiring to mess things up. In one lab I work in we have numerous 'serial cables' that are made from CAT5 patches clipped into DB9-to-RJ45 ends. I can get glitchy comms on these even at 9600, but replace with a 'real' serial cable and the same setup can run glitch free at 115200. Just sayin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a subtle "gotcha" in asynchronous serial communications — if there are never any gaps in the data that are at least as long as a character time, it's possible for the receiver to get out of sync with respect to the byte boundaries, and there's no way to recover. Any '1' followed by a '0' could be construed as being a stop bit/start bit pair.

One possible fix would be to send a byte of all-zeros (or all-ones) every now and then. If the receiver is out of sync, this will force it to resynchronize on the next start bit.

Comment: But if that is the case then shouldn't it have worked properly when only one character was sent from the microcontroller? I wrote similar code for the controller to echo what was sent from the PC, and when I sent one character the controller sometimes transmitted a different character.

Comment: You didn't say that. I can only respond to the information you put in your question, which was about continuous transmission.

Comment: This is where a scope would be useful.